# Who is that? (About family relations)

Tags: knowledge, family

> My grandpa's grandma's dad's daughter's son's mom's grandson's grandson's dad's mom's dad's daughter's grandpa's grandma's dad's daughter's son's mom's grandson's grandson's dad's mom's dad's daughter's granddaughter.

Who is that? I'm new to ***Puzzling*** so please forgive me if there are any mistakes.

Comment: With respect to [my comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118287/who-is-that-about-family-relations#comment330640_118288) on the accepted answer, this is (unfortunately) another question that has many different possible correct answers so I have voted to close... Please don't be too deterred though - keep creating and looking for little gems to share!

Comment: I will continue to create :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let something multiplied by $x$ be one generation above, and something multiplied by $1/x$ be one generation below the current generation. Assume your generation's value is one, or $x^0$. Then the value of the generation of the person mentioned in statement is:

> $$(x^2\cdot x^2\cdot x\cdot x^{-1}\cdot x^{-1} \cdot x\cdot x^{-2}\cdot x^{-2} \cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x^{-1})^2\cdot x^{-2}$$

> Which is $x^2$. Since the last word is "granddaughter", and there has been no mention of aunts, uncles, nieces and nephews, the answer is probably your **grandma**.

Comment: This answer is half right :)

Comment: Gender is wrong :)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, I edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139719/discussion-between-cheese-cake-and-my-car).

Comment: Of course this answer assumes that we stay in the same family line throughout. If the first 'daughter' mentioned is actually the *sister* of the first 'grandma' (i.e. *not* the same person) we end up in an entirely different branch of the family, with bucketloads of opportunities to diverge further from the family line used in your answer... This question thus has no unique solution but a large number of different possible answers.

Comment: Plus, the calculation of what "level" of the family tree we end up on might be incorrect, for example if cross-generational incest occurred.